# Filter Drag/Drop NSViews With CFBundleDocumentTypes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, dry, info.plist

I have a Drag/Drop `NSView` which should accept the same file types and extensions that I have listed in my `plist` under the key `CFBundleDocumentTypes`. The app accepts any type of video file, folders and several file extensions that aren't picked up by the `public.movie` type.

The (rather long) list of `CFBundleDocumentTypes` is:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Folder</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fold</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Movies</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.movie</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>flv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Flash Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ram</string>
            <string>rm</string>
            <string>rmvb</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>RealPlayer Media Files</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>vob</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>VOB File (DVD Video)</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ogm</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Ogg MPEG-4 Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ogv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>video/ogg</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Ogg Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>axv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>video/annodex</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Annodex Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>avi</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>AVI container</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>mov</string>
            <string>moov</string>
            <string>qt</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>video/quicktime</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Apple QuickTime container</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>divx</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>DivX file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>dv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>DV file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>wmv</string>
            <string>wm</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Windows Media Video</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>mpg</string>
            <string>mpeg</string>
            <string>mpeg1</string>
            <string>mpeg2</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>multiplexed MPEG-1/2</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>m1v</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MPEG-1 Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ts</string>
            <string>m2ts</string>
            <string>mts</string>
            <string>mt2s</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>video/mp2t</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MPEG-2 Transport Stream</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>m2v</string>
            <string>mpv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MPEG-2 Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>mp4</string>
            <string>mpeg4</string>
            <string>m4v</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MPEG-4 File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>3gp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>3GPP File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>mkv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Matroska Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>webm</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>WebM Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>nuv</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>NuppleVideo File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPersistentStoreTypeKey</key>
        <string>Binary</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I am already able to verify drop acceptance in my NSView's `draggingEntered` method, but I want to be able to run through the `Info.plist` entries for `CFBundleDocumentTypes` instead of duplicating all the entries in this method. How can I do this so that my view accepts the exact same files as listed in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask your bundle for the information:

```
NSArray* documentTypes = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
                                    objectForKey:@"CFBundleDocumentTypes"];
```

This will return an array of dictionaries, one for each of the file types, from which you can easily extract the other information:

```
for(NSDictionary* docInfo in documentTypes)
{
    NSArray* fileExtensions = [docInfo objectForKey:@"CFBundleTypeExtensions"];
    //do something with this info
}
```

You could use this in conjunction with the `-documentClassForType:` method of `NSDocumentController`. This takes the value from the `CFBundleTypeName` `Info.plist` key as the type.

Comment: Right, but I would still have to write code that compares the extensions and goes through these elements. What I am looking for is an API method, perhaps even the same API method that is used to determine if a file can be opened by the app. Something along the lines of [[NSApplication sharedApplication] canOpenFile:draggedFile]; If i just implement it like you have, I will have to edit this method every time a new document type is added or deleted from the plist, making it not very DRY

Comment: Why would you need to do that? The code I posted parses the `Info.plist` file dynamically and will always give you the current list of file types.

Comment: I added a note about an `NSDocumentController` method that might be useful to you.

Comment: This does indeed work, but I was hoping for something cleaner